# Is there a lightning alternative to ViewAllActivityHistoryPage?

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience, activities, migration, activityhistory

We have a custom link created on Case object that has a URL as :

`{!$Site.Domain}/ui/core/activity/ViewAllActivityHistoryPage?&id={!Account.Id}`

In this, from what I understand is that, ViewAllActivityHistoryPage is a standard SF apex page and it'll show all the activity history record details related to 'id' of the object.(In this case accounts). In classic experience, this  opens in a separate window tab. Is there any corresponding feature in lightning experience for the same so that users are not redirected to a classic UI page?

I know we can open the same page in lightning experience, but that will still show the UI with classic style. Can we have this page in lightning without any new custom development?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have a corresponding standard lightning app which shows the history and is invoked on click of "View All" on activity history standard component.

`https://domain.lightning.force.com/runtime_sales_activities/activityViewAll.app?parentRecordId={ID}`

We can invoke this URL on click of a custom button in lightning experience and pass the recordId for which we want to show the history (Ex: show related account history on click of button on case object.)

Comment: Above link always open in lightening mode even if selected view is classic.
Is there any link which redirects automatically based on view settings of user?

Comment: @MayankSAgnihotri : I don't think there is any link that re-directs automatically based on selected experience. But if possible you can control it from your code conditionally routing to a particular URL based on selected experience. Classic URL is : `{!$Site.Domain}/ui/core/activity/ViewAllActivityHistoryPage?&id={!Account.Id}
` as mentioned in question.